# Как отключить экран демонстрации обновления Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, update

Иногда, когда на компьютер приходят обновления, после перезагрузки вылезает экран с примерно следующим содержанием "Привет! Мы подготавливаем ваш компьютер".

Примерно вот так это выглядит:

[image]

Все это жутко действует на нервы, и я хочу узнать, можно ли отключить такой экран, при этом не отказываясь от обновлений?

Comment: Вряд ли Вам удастся избавиться от такого сообщения. В это время происходит обновление системы, что, разумеется, занимает какое-то время.

Comment: @koshe такое окно появляется как правило при совершенно неважных обновлениях. Я имею ввиду, рекламных, после которых в меню пуск появляется куча всяких ненужных приложений из магазина windows. Мнне кажется, что где-то этот экран должен отключаться